# Yml files in Play framework: can they refer to one another

Tags: java, playframework, yaml

In my application, I want to initialize it with large data. when I wrote all these data in one YML file it was about 4 MB but then the application didn't start making a java heap space error. when I remove some parts of it till 109 KB, everything works but of course with some missing data.

My expectation to solve this problem is one of the following:

1. make more than one file, But how to refer to an object in another YML file, is this possible?
2. Load a schema into the database via code at start up, is this easy to make?
3. a solution proposed by any of this question readers ...

Note: most of the data in my application refers to each other so I couldn't separate them in more than one file totally.

Comment: Can we assume that all the data in one file was larger than 4KB, and that you *do* run out of heap?

Comment: In fact, the YML files makes you independent on the underling database type, this is a very useful feature

so I really need to seek a solution for it first.

Comment: I still can't see how 4MB of text data is going to run you out of memory - I'd suggest that if you solve that problem you aren't going to need multiple files.

Comment: I really solved it for now by using about 30 files each of them is about 100KB, and the objects reference worked among the files. I named them data.yml, data_1.yml, data_2.yml and so on. thenI wrote a code to load each of them. still I feel there is another way to use one file but I don;t know how. I think increasing the memory worked with me too, but double the memory when the application doesn;t need to, it is just the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at DBUnit to dump and reload your whole DB, assuming it's SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that on a startup Job:

```
@Override
public void doJob() {
    if (Image.count() == 0 && Play.mode.equals(Play.Mode.DEV)) {
        Fixtures.deleteAllModels();
        List<Image> images = Fixtures.loadYaml("Images.yml", List.class); //<-- this just loads the image objects (not in db yet)
        Fixtures.loadModels("Albums.yml"); // <----- this puts albums into db
        int i = 0;
        for (Image img : images) {
            img.album = Album.find("byName", img.album.name).first();
            img.save(); // <--- here image entities go into db
            i++;
        }
    }
```